# Is it safe to disable temporarily SQL_SAFE_UPDATES to perform a mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, unsafe

Sometimes I end up to need to perform update like the following:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
//My update query [..]
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

While I perform those three above statements... SQL_SAFE_UPDATES configuration is disabled.
Since I believe that this setup has a clear meaning. 
What could be the drawback on disabling temporary this feature?

Is there a chance to enclose all the statements in a atomic transaction ? To prevent others to execute unsafe queries in the meanwhile?

Comment: "what could be the drawback of not wearing seatbelts while driving? it's only for a few minutes while I change clothes, eat breakfast, put on makeup, and send a few dozen texts from my cell. what could possibly go wrong?"

Comment: Why would you need to do that unless your update query was poorly written (i.e. not containing appropriate specificity) to begin with?  One typically would not want their application being able to make updates across all records in a table without using a key column in `WHERE` or setting a record `LIMIT`. That sort of update could have disastrous performance impact.

Comment: Setting a LIMIT will not prevent the error and stopping the update. And yes update may be poorly written, or db structure too.

Answer (score 0):

Safe updates are better summed up with the alternative command-line argument "--i-am-a-dummy". Other than removing some power from your query, they don't make it any "safer". They insist on limits to queries, conditions on removes etc which are *single-shot checks*. To use Marc B's analogy, it's not whether you will crash the car but whether the car will explode when you turn the key. If it doesn't the first time then it's not going to the next. It's more akin to asking "is it okay to run a command with sudo under Linux" - perhaps not in a general way but sometimes you can't achieve anything unless you do.

In this case, all you're saying when you turn it off is "I know what I'm doing so just get on with it and stop moaning." If you're happy with the query and that it does what you want it to then there's no need to set the safe updates at all.

I never even knew it existed. You build up the query, check that it looks right, backup the table, run the query, check the results and call it good. After your second or third system, your SQL errors aren't going to be simple enough to be caught by this anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for sharing your philosophy Mike, but i'm not looking after a recommendation on good programming. I ask this question because sometimes the environment, the code, and the time given are not clean and perfect has we would. So you need to get your hands dirty and perform something quick. Like querying an update to adjust data.  I wish there was a way to perform this "quick" task in a safer way. Sometimes a "no there's no other way" answer could be quicker and more positive.